# "NOT NULL", "IS NOT NULL" does not display in the table

Tags: php, mysql, database

**PROBLEM** 
*Null column and Not null column does not display at the table*

**Explainaton**
*I want to display all result at rank column from different database table which is Table 1 until table 4 below, but it only display for those who already have 4 result data. How can i achive this? Sorry im new in database field. I hope you guys can give me some reference or related *

> My query

```
<?php
                   $sql = "SELECT virtualexam.rank.id, virtualexam.rank.username,

                   virtualexam.rank.score AS score, virtualexam1.rank.score AS 'score1', virtualexam2.rank.score AS 'score2', virtualexam3.rank.score AS 'score3',

                   SUM(virtualexam.rank.score + virtualexam1.rank.score + virtualexam2.rank.score + virtualexam3.rank.score ) AS 'total' 
                   
                   FROM virtualexam.rank
               
                   JOIN virtualexam1.rank ON (virtualexam.rank.username =  virtualexam1.rank.username) 
               
                   JOIN virtualexam2.rank ON (virtualexam2.rank.username =  virtualexam1.rank.username)
               
                  JOIN virtualexam3.rank ON (virtualexam3.rank.username =  virtualexam2.rank.username) 

                  WHERE virtualexam.rank.score IS NULL OR virtualexam.rank.score = ''
                 
                  GROUP BY virtualexam.rank.username ; ";


                  $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

?>

[my html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHweV.png)

[db.Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5SCO.png)

[db1.Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTJ4B.png)

[db2.Table 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQ0g.png)

[db3.Table 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkgXQ.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say just `JOIN`, it requires a record to exist in the joined table.  If you want it to be optional, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.  Then if the joined table doesn't exist, references to columns in it will give NULL.  To keep your `virtualexam.rank.score + virtualexam1.rank.score + virtualexam2.rank.score + virtualexam3.rank.score` from returning NULL when any of the things being added are NULL, you need to use coalesce.  So:

```
SELECT
    virtualexam.rank.id,
    virtualexam.rank.username,
    virtualexam.rank.score AS score,
    virtualexam1.rank.score AS 'score1',
    virtualexam2.rank.score AS 'score2',
    virtualexam3.rank.score AS 'score3',
    SUM(COALESCE(virtualexam.rank.score,0) + COALESCE(virtualexam1.rank.score,0) + COALESCE(virtualexam2.rank.score,0) + COALESCE(virtualexam3.rank.score) ) AS 'total' 
FROM virtualexam.rank
LEFT JOIN virtualexam1.rank ON (virtualexam.rank.username = virtualexam1.rank.username) 
LEFT JOIN virtualexam2.rank ON (virtualexam2.rank.username = virtualexam1.rank.username)
LEFT JOIN virtualexam3.rank ON (virtualexam3.rank.username = virtualexam2.rank.username) 
WHERE virtualexam.rank.score IS NULL OR virtualexam.rank.score = ''                 
GROUP BY virtualexam.rank.username
```

This still only reports users who have a virtualexam.rank entry.  If you want to include those who don't but do have an entry in any of the other databases, you have to do:

```
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT username FROM virtualexam.rank
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT username FROM virtualexam1.rank
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT username FROM virtualexam2.rank
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT username FROM virtualexam3.rank
) AS users
LEFT JOIN virtualexam.rank ON virtualexam.rank.username=users.username
LEFT JOIN virtualexam1.rank ON virtualexam1.rank.username=users.username
LEFT JOIN virtualexam2.rank ON virtualexam2.rank.username=users.username
LEFT JOIN virtualexam3.rank ON virtualexam3.rank.username=users.username
```

But this is a very poor database design.  Put all your scores in a single table, with other fields to identify what the score is for.

Comment: im sorry for the database design because it from previous developer, my job is to create dashboard from the data inside database..Anyway thank you so much for your response.

Comment: its work great!. But after i remove {WHERE clause} why?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your where clause?  It didn't make much sense to me